# asp.net validation related problem

Tags: asp.net, validation

This event belongs to form view

```
protected void companyForm_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{ 
    some logic 
}
```

I have some customValidator (server side) i want to know y i dont need to check page.isvalid property in above event... while in some events i have to check it otherwise  event code is processed despite failure of validation...

Comment: please resolve my  problem i have been searching for long but not getting any valid result...

Comment: whats wrong with this question